# initializing value to the double pointer without taking any new variables

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int **ptr;
    /* Lines of code*/
    printf("%d",**ptr);
}
```

insert lines in the above code so that answer should be 4 but without

initializing any new variables.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: its a `pointer to a pointer to int`. You want to cross two bridges without stepping on an intermediate island?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int*));
*ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
**ptr = 4;
```

Comment: Thank u so much.This was my interview questions and it was eating up my time.It works fine.